# Why did the same question get displayed two different ways?

Tags: support, search

Both questions are same when I click either of the links, but somehow in SO it shows the link twice with different information.

[Whats wrong in this code , its been identified as Wrong answer by the online judge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68509958/whats-wrong-in-this-code-its-been-identified-as-wrong-answer-by-the-online-jud/68510592#68510592)

[image: The first link is prepended with "A:" and shows a vote score of 2. The second link is prepended with "Q:", shows a vote score of -4, 2 answers, and indicates one is accepted. The summary for each link is different.]

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: *[A new search engine for Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/)*. There may be other/better duplicates.

Answer (score 10):

They're not links to the same thing.

The first one is a link to an answer to the question - as indicated by the "A:" before the title.

The second one is a link to the question itself - it has a "Q:" before the title and a box indicating the number of answers (2) below the score. The solid green colour shows that it has an accepted answer.

Comment: But it shouldn't get displayed like this right, as clicking any of those goes to same question.

Comment: @InQusitive No, clicking the first one opens the same page but jumps to the answer. If you want the search results to return questions only, add `is:q` or `is:question` in the search box.

Comment: @41686d6564: Was it always like this. I didn't change any setting options.

Comment: @InQusitive one links to an answer - it should have `#<postid>` at the end of the url -  the other links to the question.

Comment: @InQusitive Yes, search results have always included questions and answers. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for more search operators.

Comment: @41686d6564: Always = since December 2012?